# AWS EC2 Windows server with S3 storage for Veeam backup

Tags: amazon-ec2, backup, amazon-s3, cloud, veeam

I want to create a remote repository for the backup of my local infrastructure.
I'm using Veeam v10.

I think I need a remote machine with a Veeam component installed, then I was wondering if I can build a EC2 Windows machine with Veeam with S3 as storage.

The goal is to transfer from my site to EC2 only the incremental backup (I cannot transfer a full with my bandwith!) and let the machine compute and merge backup in a reverse incremental backup.
Is this a good configuration?
Is it possibile to use EC2 with a S3 storage for veeam repository?

Answer (score 7):

You can actually connect to S3 bucket from EC2 instance.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/
So you can build it. However, in case you have Veeam Enterprise and Enterprise Plus editions you can use SOBR to configure AWS S3 as a backup repository.
https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/adding_amazon_object_storage.html?ver=100
Another possible alternative is to use StarWind VTL free to store backups directly to AWS S3.
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-cloud-vtl-for-veeam

Comment: Thanks for your time @Stuka, I'll take a look at your links.

Comment: All these solutions need only incrementals?

Comment: You can configure file to tape job in case of VTL to backup incrementals. 
https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/file_to_tape_hiw.html?ver=100
With Veeam SOBR you can choose were to place backup files.
https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/backup_repository_sobr_placement.html?ver=100